# ImageIO.read retorna null quando InputStream uso jersey

Tags: java, java-ee, jersey, inputstream

Eu tenho o seguinte problema

Eu tenho o seguinte serviço:

```
@PUT
@Path("/validateQRCode")
@Logging
@Permissions(allAllowed = true)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response validateQRCode(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream  file) throws Exception{
    return Response.ok().entity(qrCodeManager.validateQRCode(file)).build();
}
```

E tenho a seguinte classe responsável pelo "negócio":

```
public QRCodeTO validateQRCode(InputStream  file) throws BusinessException {
        BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(file);
        ....
}
```

O problema é que o objeto que recebo pelo serviço (objeto file não está nulo) quando utilizo o método ImageIO.read(file) ele retorna NULL...Pesquisei N artigos e todos os exemplos se baseam nesta forma de utilização.